# Why is my random generation of numbers input all zeros?

Tags: c++, templates, random, vector

I have a function template that is suppose to take a vector and produce random numbers inside it.
However, when I print entire vector, its all zeros. This method works for arrays however.

code:

```
#include <vector>

template<class T> 
class RandomGenerator
{
public:
    // function template for generating random numbers
 void genRand(T data[], int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (1 + rand() % size);
        }
    }



 void genRand(std::vector<T> data, int size)
    {
        genRand(&data[0], size);
    }



};
```

Comment: Agree with reference, but does `&data[0]` not result in a `T*` type which mean that memory is not being automatically allocated in the `vector<T>` when you do the `data[i] = value` -- so I would expect memory curruption here due to writing outside of boundary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You take the vector by value, thus the argument won't be changed. Take it by reference:

```
 void genRand(std::vector<T>& data, int size)
 //                         ^
```